# how to change special characters sent from view to template python/django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem - trying to send object from view.py file into template, but apostrophe is converted to

> "& quot;"

.

This is my code:

view.py file:

```
total['test'] = {}
total['test']['2017-02-10'] = 2000
total['test']['2017-03-10'] = 25000
total['test']['2017-04-10'] = 20400
total['test']['2017-05-10'] = 24000

return render(request, 'homepage.html', {
    'total' : json.dumps(total),
})
```

template:

```
<script>
    console.log( JSON.stringify( {{ total}} ) );
</script>
```

And result:

> console.log( JSON.stringify( {& quot;test& quot;:
>   {& quot;2017-02-10& quot;: 2000, & quot;2017-03-10& quot;: 25000,
>   & quot;2017-04-10& quot;: 20400, & quot;2017-05-10& quot;: 24000 } } )

I had to add the space between "&" and quot because of auto-convert this characters by stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried {{ total|safe }} in your html?

Comment: You are sending the data from the view, using `json.dumps(data)`. Its already a string. Then, why did you `stringify` it again. Just, try `console.log()` the variable.

Comment: {{ total|safe }} solved my problem, thanks a lot !

Comment: @FazilZaid ,nothing change if I remove JSON.stringify  :-) thanks guys !